# Ip address GetHostName Null Check

Tags: c#, dns, ip, reverse-dns

I want to get domain names from specific ip range with C#

```
 IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse("100.10.100."+i);
    entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(addr);
```

But I encountered this error 
*The requested name is valid and was found in the database, but it does not have the correct associated data being resolved for*

Some Ip hasn't domain names.But I can't null check  GetHostEntry.
I tried like that but nothing changed.I encountered same error

```
 if(Dns.GetHostEntry(addr)!=null)
```

How can I make null check for bypass this error?

Comment: seems like you need to catch the exception to verify null

Comment: @Jonesy I missed try catch function.It solved problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the try-catch statement in C#:

```
  for (int i = 1; i <= 255; i++) {
    IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse("100.10.100."+i);
    try
    {
      entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(addr);
      //some other codes that cause exception
    }
    catch(SocketException ex)
    {
      //do something
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      //catch all other exceptions
    }
  }
```